# Awk command to compare specific columns in file1 to file2 and display output

Tags: awk

File1

```
111,222,560,0.7
111,333,560,0.2
111,444,560,0.1
```

File2

```
2017,111,560,0.0537
2018,111,560,0.0296
2019,111,560,0.0624
```

Desired output:

```
2017,111,560,0.0537,222,0.7
2018,111,560,0.0296,222,0.7
2019,111,560,0.0624,222,0.7
2017,111,560,0.0537,333,0.2
2018,111,560,0.0296,333,0.2
2019,111,560,0.0624,333,0.2
2017,111,560,0.0537,444,0.1
2018,111,560,0.0296,444,0.1
2019,111,560,0.0296,444,0.1
```

I tried awk `NR==FNR` command but it’s displaying only the last matched...

reads every line and check if column 1 and 3 of file1 exists in file2:

```
2017,111,560,0.0537,444,0.1
2018,111,560,0.0296,444,0.1
2019,111,560,0.0296,444,0.1
```

Comment: awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","} NR==FNR{a[$1$3]=$2","$4;next}($2$3 in a){print $0, a[$2$3]}' File1 File2

this is the command I used but I want to see all match.. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F, '
FNR==NR{
  a[FNR]=$0;
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){
    print a[i] FS $2 FS $NF
}
}'   Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Adding explanation too for code as follows.

```
awk -F, '                   ##Setting field separator as comma here for all the lines.
FNR==NR{                    ##Using FNR==NR condition which will be only TRUE then first Input_file named File2 is being read.
                            ##FNR and NR both indicates the number of lines for a Input_file only difference is FNR value will be RESET whenever a new file is being read and NR value will be keep increasing till all Input_files are read.
  a[FNR]=$0;                ##Creating an array named a whose index is FNR(current line) value and its value is current line value.
  next                      ##Using next statement will sip all further statements now.
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++){##Starting a for loop from variable i value from 1 to length of array a value. This will be executed on 2nd Input_file reading.
    print a[i] FS $2 FS $NF ##Printing the value of array a whose index is variable i and printing 2nd and last field of current line.
}
}' File2 File1              ##Mentioning the Input_file names here.
```

Comment: hi ravinder, thank you.. I encountered an error when trying to execute your solution:
awk: Cannot read the value of  a. It is an array name.

 The input line number is 1. The file is cml_rdf_delieo_bom_143.dat_spread.
 The source line number is 7.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried awk NR==FNR command but it’s displaying only the last
>   matched...
>
> reads every line and check if column 1 and 3 of file1 exists in file2:

Using `awk` and `sort`

```
awk 'BEGIN{
           # set input and output field separator
           FS=OFS=","               
     }
     # read first file f1
     # index key field1 and field3 of file1 (f1)
     {
         k=$1 FS $3
     }

     # save 2nd and last field of file1 (f1) in array a, key being k
     FNR==NR{
         a[k]=(k in a ? a[k] RS:"") $2 OFS $NF; 

         # stop processing go to next line
         next
     }

     # read 2nd file f2 from here 
     # 2nd and 3rd field of fiel2 (f2) used as key
     {
         k=$2 FS $3
     }

     # if key exists in array a
     k in a{
         # split array value by RS row separator, and put it in array t
         split(a[k],t,RS); 

         # iterate array t, print and sort
         for(i=1; i in t; i++)
              print $0,t[i] | "sort -t, -nk5" 
     }
     ' f1 f2
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat f1
111,222,560,0.7
111,333,560,0.2
111,444,560,0.1

$ cat f2
2017,111,560,0.0537
2018,111,560,0.0296
2019,111,560,0.0624

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{k=$1 FS $3}FNR==NR{a[k]=(k in a ? a[k] RS:"") $2 OFS $NF; next}{k=$2 FS $3}k in a{split(a[k],t,RS); for(i=1; i in t; i++)print $0,t[i] | "sort -t, -nk5" }' f1 f2
2017,111,560,0.0537,222,0.7
2018,111,560,0.0296,222,0.7
2019,111,560,0.0624,222,0.7
2017,111,560,0.0537,333,0.2
2018,111,560,0.0296,333,0.2
2019,111,560,0.0624,333,0.2
2017,111,560,0.0537,444,0.1
2018,111,560,0.0296,444,0.1
2019,111,560,0.0624,444,0.1
```

Comment: oh yessss you just save me :)  you're a genius!

Comment: As per your requirement it checks column 1 and 3 exists in other file

Answer (score 0):

another one with `join/awk`

```
$ join -t, -j99 file2 file1 | 
  awk -F, -v OFS=, '$3==$6 && $4==$8 {print $2,$3,$4,$5,$7,$9}'
```

Comment: hi can you explain please :)
what does the -j99 means?